# Should I disclose our relationship when sponsoring my boyfriend's trip to the US?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, russian-citizens, invitation-letters

He is a Russian citizen lives in China on an M-visa (business visa), and previously studied in a Chinese college. He is gapping a year from college to do business in China. I am an F-1 visa holder here in the United States.

He is currently self-employed, has real estate back in Russia, but no much of money on his bank account. I am going to cover all his travel expense here (as sponsor on document).

I wish to invite him over for a summer vacation, but we have been told by many people he's chance to get denied is very high. What should we do to increase his chance to get the B2 visa?

Should we hide our relationship? Really wish to see him but I can't go to China due to my study. then how can we explain this sponsorship?

Comment: we will tell the truth - but here is the thing, how to make the truth sounds more favourable? and honestly, is there actually any chance for him to get it anyways base on his background? I have money but he doesn't. there's no financial problem just the problem of our relationship. is the relationship damaging his chance? or should we just say - I'm a good friend of him kindly offer him the money to visit me?

Comment: btw, should we hide our relationship anyways? I am better off a friend or girlfriend?

Comment: @pnuts Did you intentionally leave out "the whole truth"? ;)

Comment: This question should probably be reworded as "should we volunteer xxx information" as opposed to "should we hide xxx information".

Comment: Where did you meet? How much time have you spent together phyiscally and where was that?

Comment: well, he's application is rejected and they suggested him to get married first and apply F2. I do not understand why it is so and do not know if it will actually increase his chance to get a visa but thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Write the truth. Know that in USA immigration law material misrepresentation including by omission or fraud both lead to bars from entering the USA.

> Fraud happens when an alien misrepresented a fact;to an authorized
>   official of the United States; the fact was material;the alien did so
>   willfully; and for the purpose of obtaining a visa, other
>   documentation or entry into this country, or to obtain some other
>   immigration and naturalization benefit.

https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/Print/PolicyManual-Volume8-PartJ.html

It appears to me this clearly falls under fraud and/or willful misrepresentation IF you do not document your relationship because it is essentially inevitable that he will be asked of who is sponsoring him and the relationship to whom he is visiting. Now if perchance miraculously it is not asked in the interview, then you guys are free and clear if you don't volunteer it but I don't see how.

If the relationship is serious with potential to become something along the lines of marriage down the line, realize that a determination of fraud at this time or any time down the line will potentially make him inadmissible to the USA and barred from either getting an immigrant visa or adjusting status without getting a waiver which is difficult to get and should not be something you should even dare to knowingly fall into

Don't risk it, too much to lose and relatively little to gain.

Comment: thank you for your advice! he was rejected a few days ago and been told that it's better for him to marry me first and apply for F2 visa. why so? we do not understand. and is that wise for him to apply B2 visa again in his home country? he is russian citizen and he got rejected in China (he is currently studying in china).

Comment: Because if you marry him, and the marriage is genuine and you can show you have the money to take care of him when he comes here, the chances of him getting the visa are much much much higher than getting visitors visa. I was an F1 student here 19 years ago so I know how that works.

Comment: Generally USA likes to keep families together (apart from _illegal_) aliens. But don't marry your boyfriend **JUST** because you want to get him a visa. Marry for love and because you want to make a life together and only when you're ready.